# Как узнать входную точку программы?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, main

У меня на руках проект, где несколько сотен файлов, и где то среди них спрятана функция Main(). У меня нету ничего, кроме файлов, и не у кого спросить где входная точка программы. Проект написан на c#.
Если ли способ из vs code как бы поставить программу на паузу в САМОМ начале её выполнения, чтоб я просто понял где входная точка?

Comment: Есть встроенный поиск по тексту в проекте `ctrl`+`shift`+`f` или в меню можно найти.

Comment: В конфиге файла добавьте опцию `"stopAtEntry": true`

Comment: А как это сделать? Я не могу найти stopentry свойство для csproj файлов

Comment: @Kemsikov `stopAtEntry`, а не `stopEntry`

Comment: @Kemsikov это не для `.csproj`, а для `.vscode/launch.json` – выбираете ваш конфиг для запуска и вперёд!

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: @Kemsikov вам лучше меня пинговать, чтобы я мог увидеть ваши сообщения; делается это так: `@<чей-либо ник>`, например, `@return`. Благодаря этому у человека, которого вы пингуете, в inbox'е появится сообщение о том, что вы его пинганули. Это работает и в Discord, и в ВК, и много еще где.

Answer (score 1):

Для остановки следует добавить опцию `stopAtEntry`:

<sub>`.vscode/launch.json`</sub>

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            ⋮
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            ⋮
        }
    ]
}
```

Подробнее об опции `stopAtEntry` можно прочитать [тут](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes).